# Is it possible to run a report to see who has access to the Application Insights instances on the Azure Subscriptions?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Is it possible to run a report to see who has access to the Application Insights instances on the Azure Subscriptions?

If yes , then how to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below PowerShell script to check contributor & owner of a particular application insights under a specific resource group.

```
$resourceGroup = "RGNAME"
$resourceName = "AppInsightsName"
$resourceType = "microsoft.insights/components"
(Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroup $resourceGroup -ResourceType $resourceType -ResourceName $resourceName | Where-Object {$_.RoleDefinitionName -in @('Owner', 'Contributor') } | Select -ExpandProperty SignInName | Sort-Object -Unique) -Join ", "
```

If a particular user is assigned with `Application Insights component contributor` role he will be having access to all the application insights that were present under a particular subscription.

If any of the user has any of  the below [RBAC roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/resources-roles-access-control#select-a-role) that were listed in documentation will be able to access the application insights.

As per the RBAC roles you can try making changes to the PowerShell script according to your requirement.

For  more information about  Resources, roles, and access control in Application Insights you refer this [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/resources-roles-access-control#to-provide-access-to-another-user)